# Post to my page wall from server with no interaction on my behalf

Tags: php, facebook

I've spent a lot of time researching answers on SO and other sites with no avail, so it's time to ask by myself.

I want to post to a Page I am an owner, without doing any authentication in the browser - I want my server to automatically login, get all required access tokens, get permissions and post to the wall. No popups, no redirects, it should be able to do it with no supervision, for example as a CRON job running for months.

Is this even possible to accomplish this? I can store my user credentials on the server, it's not a problem for me. The best I've managed to find is the 60 days access token but it's far from perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this through cron job, you just need the verified access token to work offline.

For getting the access token, go through this discussion: [Error validating access token](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/14007430/error-validating-access-token-session-has-expired-at-unix-time/14010052#14010052)